# How to distribute a value over a set of segments based on a 1 basis

Tags: python, c, algorithm

## Problem description

We have a set of integers values between `[1,..,4]`. We want to distribute a specific value into segments of different lengths between `[1,...,10]` on a **1 basis**.

We show an example in the following table:

```
   Example Value  segments  distribution
    a       4       4          1 on each segment
    b       3       4          1 on the first 3 segments
    c       3       2          2 on the first segment ( 1 + 1) and 1 on the second segment
```

My solution was the following:

- if  value >= segments then loop over the segment and add 1 to each one of them till dispatch becomes equal to **value**
- if value < segments then loop on the segments in a decreasing order and add 1 to each of them till we reach the first segment. Do the difference between **value** and the total of 1s then add it to the first segment

---

## Source code

all the examples (a, b, c) are represented in the following code. with the following output:

```
#example a [1, 1, 1, 1]
#example b [1, 1, 1, 0]
#example c [2, 1]

#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import re
import sys
import argparse


if __name__ == "__main__":
    threshold = 4

    #(a) value = 3 and segments = 4
    dispatch = 1
    value = 4 + 1
    seg1 = [0,0,0,0]
    for i in range(0, len(seg1)):
        if dispatch == value:
            break
        seg1[i] += 1
        dispatch += 1

    print ("example a %s" %seg1)

    # (b) value = 3 and segments = 4
    dispatch = 1
    value = 3 + 1
    seg2 = [0,0,0,0]
    for i in range(0, len(seg2)):
        if dispatch == value:
            break
        seg2[i] += 1
        dispatch += 1

    print ("example b %s" %seg2)

    # (c) value = 3 and segments = 2
    value = 3 + 1
    dispatch = 1
    seg3 = [0,0]
    for i in range(len(seg3) - 1, -1, -1):
        if i == 0:
            seg3[i] = value - dispatch
            break
        seg3[i] += 1
        dispatch += 1

    print ("example c %s" %seg3)
```

---

## Question

I find the solution that I am using really Ugly. I couldn't deduce a formula out of the examples. Is there a formula that we can deduce from the examples? that would make the algorithm have like a formula behind it lol

> My code is in C but i found it easier to represent it in python in
> here.

Comment: If your code works and you're looking for a more elegant way, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thank you @jsheeran  but I am trying to find a mathematical formula or a better way to do the algorithm. I am trying of see if we can find a pseudo code.

Comment: *"My code is in C but i found it easier to represent it in python in here."* How comes? You could just copy/paste your C code to here and use the editiors "Code example" button (the one looking like `{}`; select your just pasted piece of code for before). No need for producing duplicate code in different languages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematical formula is quite easy:

```
value / segments
```

gives you the number of items you have to place into each segment at least

```
value % segments
```

gives you the number of segments that receive an extra item

With your examples:

```
                      v/s    v%s
a       4       4      1      0
b       3       4      0      3
c       3       2      1      1
```

With that, you get quite an easy algorithm:

```
unsigned int n = value/segments;
unsigned int c = value%segments;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < segments; ++i)
    theSegments[i] = n + (i < c);
```

Or, if you want to skip the array:

```
unsigned int f(unsigned int values, unsigned int segments, theSegment)
{
    // assuming theSegment being checked for < segments
    return value/segments + (theSegment < value%segments) 
}
```

If you want to use a 1-based array (having index 0 as dummy):

```
for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= segments; ++i)
    theSegments[i] = n + (i <= c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Some information that might be useful in implementation :

Let `V` be total number of values and `S` be the total number of Segments.

1) Minimum number of values each segment will get : `V/S`. (Consider Integer division).

2)Now we are left with `V%S` values as each of the `S` segments will get `V/S` values.
For `V%S` values, you can just run a loop from `1 to V%S` and add `1` to each of the segments.

**Code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int V=10;  //no. of values
    int S=4;   //no. of segments

    int arr[4];  //Considering 0-based indexing
    int minimumValues = V/S;
    int remaining = V%S;
    for(int i=0;i<S;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=minimumValues;

        if(i<remaining)
            arr[i]++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<S;i++)
        printf("%d, ",arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```